# Expat moving out of the US filing tax return

Tags: taxes, usa, tax-treaties, tax-deductions

I am a F-1 student living in the US, planning to move away from the country by the end of next year. As a student, I have a tax deduction per tax treaties for my income, and I want to claim this benefit.

However, I'm planning to move out of the country before the end of next year. Can I, and how should I file my tax return for 2019 to claim and receive my tax benefits?

Answer (score 1):

A person living outside the US files US federal tax returns by mail to an address in Austin TX, as detailed in [this US government IRS page](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxpayers-living-abroad). (If you're still in the US in April 2019 when your 2018 tax return is due, you'll file just like everyone else.)

The page linked above contains multiple links to assist overseas filers. IRS forms and publications are available for download, and there's contact information for help as well. It might be helpful to read IRS Publication 54, titled "US Citizens and Resident Aliens abroad." It is downloadable [here](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-54).

You may also be required to file a US state income tax return. Procedures and forms will depend on the state's laws and regulations.

Comment: However, I am not a resident alien

Comment: @xuq01@xuq01 Yes, you said that in your question. The IRS advice is directed generally at those who must file a tax return and are outside the US. I have also amended my answer to include the possibility that you'll still be in the US when it's time to file.

Comment: It's possible to be a nonresident alien while actually living in the US, perhaps paradoxically.  Note the comment "I am not a resident alien," not "I will no longer be a resident alien."